# How to align two div panels horizontally

Tags: html, css

I've created two div and aligned them left and right using css inline property, the problem is that I can't set the width and height in percentage (not in pixel value), I've seen some alternatives of this question but I didn't get the solution yet,

This is what i want : [image]

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6JgNu/ (I've used the pixel values to set height instead of percent). please update it with height in percentage value.

Here is the code :

```
<style type="text/css">
.left-panel
{        
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:10%;
    height:100px;            
}
.right-panel
{        
    background-color:Gray;
    width:90%;
    height:100px;
}
```

First panel



    Second panel

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `float:left`

```
.left-panel
{        
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:10%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;            
}
.right-panel
{        
    background-color:Gray;
    width:80%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6JgNu/5/

Comment: is it possible to set the height in percentage value

Comment: In your case, you have to use `px` for height. Percentage value will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `float:left;` to `.left-panel`. Hope this helps - good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<style>
.left-panel
{        
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:10%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;        
}
.right-panel
{        
    background-color:Gray;
    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}

</style>

<div class="left-panel"></div>
<div class="right-panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add 
    float:left 
to divs and it should work

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.left-panel
    {        
        background-color:#ccc;
        width:10%;
        height:100px;
        float:left;        
    }
    .right-panel
    {        
        background-color:Gray;
        width:90%;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
}
```